# Why is always the answer equal to 5?

Tags: c++, math

Giving this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int k, x;

    while(k > x-3) {
         k--;
         // cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
    }
    x++, k--;

    int aux = abs(k-x);
    cout << aux;
}
```

When we run it, it always pops up a constant x (x = 50) and the absolute value between the integer k and the x is always 5. Can you please explain me why and how does this works?

Comment: Actually undefined behavior because `k` and `x` are not initialized.

Comment: So what is the explanation of this program?

Comment: You're using `k` and `x` uninitialized, so this is undefined behavior anyway. That aside (assuming they are initialized to a default value), you're not taking any input or random values, so why would you expect a different result every time?

Comment: But if they were defined with a value of `k` far greater than `x`, you end up after the loop with `k = x-3`, then you increment them, and the result would be `3`. If `k` starts below `x-3`, then the result can be anything.

Comment: When you wake up tomorrow you'll see different constant value, unless that address is being over written

Comment: @AlexCiornei _"So what is the explanation of this program?"_ There's no reasonable explanation for the behavior of _undefined behavior_, at best for a very specific compiler of a very specific version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: This problem was given in an admission to a faculty, so I'm trying to understand why this is the answer and not another. Basically it says so: "in the next sequence of code, the x and k are integers. Before executing it, k is greater than x. Please say what is the value of the expression abs(k-x) at the end of the execution".

Comment: So it's an ill-posed problem because the code as is is UB, but they expect to set `k` and `x`.

Comment: I see. Got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the constraint of "`k` is greater than `x`", this piece of code here

```
while(k > x-3) {
     k--;
     // cout << "x = " << x << "\n";
}
```

Will decrease `k` to be `3` less than `x`.

The next line, `x++, k++;` increases them both by `1`, but it doesn't change the result. `k` is still `3` smaller than `x`.

`k-x` is `-3` and `abs(k-x)` is `3`, hence why the program always prints `3`. Assuming, of course, that both `k` and `x` are initialized and that `k` is bigger than `x`. The program as it is posted with `k` and `x` uninitialized exhibits undefined behavior, so there's no guarantee on what is going to happen. Also, as Aconcagua points out, if `x` is smaller than `INT_MIN + 3`, that also leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: You missed one further possibility of UB: underflow due to x being smaller than INT_MIN + 3...

Comment: @Aconcagua Good catch, I added it to the answer.

Comment: OP: "the absolute value between the integer k and the x is always **5**". This answer does not explain the observed bahavior. (@AlexC: How can you accept it? Is "5" in your question a typo?)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - The edit history clearly indicates the OP edited their post *after* this was answered. If anyone deserves flak it's them, not Blaze.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh, I never read the first version. So is it 3 or 5??

Comment: The reason why I wrote `3` was because I tested the program and the result is `3`, so I assume that the `5` is a typo, or maybe the admission question was a trick question all along.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, @Blaze - The OP edited `k++` into `k--`. Frankly, I have no idea what they want, only that they demonstrated bad netiquette.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh, I missed that. Yeah, with `k--` the result is `5`, course. He really should have mentioned that edit.

Answer (score 0):

Matthieu and πάντα ῥεῖ are correct: Ths is classic undefined behavior. (One rationale for making it *undefined* and not simply *unspecified* or *implementation defined* is that some architectures have flags for uninitialized registers and would trap.) A compiler is actually free to compile it to an empty program: Reading an uninitialized variable can result in *anything* — and *nothing* is a subset of *anything*. All subsequent code after the undefined behavior is "tainted" by the preceding error and can be omitted. Note that different architectures and different compilers, possibly even different C standard libs (with the same compiler!) may give different results; even a different *compiler flag* (concerning optimization or function call conventions) may change this undefined behavior.

(*The rest of this answer applies to the version of the question where the line after the loop read `x++, k++;` (instead of `k--` as it is now).*)

But you have encountered a consistent behavior, and the question is why it is consistent. The first assumption is that the compiler does not simply generate code to output "5", (which it could, legitimately) but actually "naively" generates machine code that corresponds to the C statements. We'll reason along the statements.

Then the behavior indicates that the memory locations where x and k reside are containing values which make `k > x -3` false right away. (Otherwise, k would be decremented until the difference is 3, not 5).

If the condition is false, the variable difference will not change; from that we can conclude that it was 5 from the start with `x-k == 5`. If you omit the `abs()`, the output should be `-5`.

The reason the variables have these consistent intial values may be connected to things the operating system or C runtime environment do at program startup, like initializing the standard streams. Try using `printf` instead of `cout` and see if the result changes.

Comment: The answer concerned a version of the question when the code read `x++, k++;`. As it now stands, 5 is the expected outcome with initial values for which `k >= x-3` is true, including the probably-not-uncommon case that both are 0. In that case Blaze's answer is correct. It is perhaps worth noting that an output of 5 is only possible if  `k >= x-3`, if I'm not mistaken. (After changing `k++` to `k--` in the question.) My hunch is that the question aimed at that insight.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you should try two arbitrary numbers.
For example , imagine we are using `k= 10 & x=8`. 
Your loop will look like: 
   `While(10>5) 10-1=9`    ... and so on, until K is not greater than (X-3).
You will get k=5, and x is the same value,8.
After the while loop you decrement k, and increment x, so k=4 and x=9.
`Abs(k-x) = 5`.

If you want the more theoretical explanation, the loop will grant that the difference between your two variables is 3, the X will be greater than K.
As after the loop you decrement K and increment X , the diference between them will ALWAYS be 5.